# Manipulate Datetime in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am using this

```
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, ec.due_date, 120), 20)) AS [time]
```

to get the date and time but I want the time in **12 hour format 06:00 AM** . Right now I am getting this `2011-11-05 00:00:00`. I want the date in the same format but not time.

Answer (score 0):

- [SQL Server CONVERT() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp)

So:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), ec.due_date, 131)
```

Gives:

> 05/11/11 02:05:01:100 AM

Answer (score 0):

Refer this URL for more formats:-

**http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx**

Some of immediate examples:-

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 100)
```

Returns output as **"Jan 1 2005 1:29PM"**

## Date Formats Representation:

***DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS:MMMAM***

DD - Date 
MM - Month 
YYYY - Year 
HH - Hours 
MI - Minutes 
SS - Seconds 
MMM - MilliSeconds 
AM - AM/PM